# Preventing Mouse-wheel scrolling of controls

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am developing an application using the MFC library and I am currently trying to prevent the user accidentally changing one of the combo box controls when they are scrolling the mouse wheel.

I am looking for a solution without deriving a new class from the `CComboBox` class and preventing the mouse scrolling there.

My understanding of the system is that Windows passes the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message to the Combo box control which handles it (scrolling the combo box) and then this is propagated up the chain of parent controls (so them to my `CFormView` etc.), which means I cannot prevent the scrolling by capturing the event in my form view.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the PreTranslateMessage handler in the main window class and look for WM_MOUSEWHEEL messages. Compare the pMsg->hwnd handle in PreTranslateMessage handler with the combobox handle, if found, filter the messages away.

Answer (score 3):

You can always derive a control from `CComboBox` and trap the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message in the control itself. Then simply use your new derived combo box in your form view.

If you don't want to create a derived class (perhaps it's too big a change for your project), you can subclass the combo box and trap the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` there.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Raymond. I didn't think about subclassing the combo box as an alternative.