# Determining type of MFC object from HWND

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

Further to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030811/preventing-mouse-wheel-scrolling-of-controls) I have decided to overwrite the `PreTranslateMessage` function of my main window `CMainFrame` to check if a `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message has been sent, and if it has and the target of the message is a combo box then prevent the message from being dispatched.

However, I am having an issue determining if the target of the message is a combo box, here is what I am currently trying:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreTranslateMessage( MSG* pMsg )
{
      CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle( pMsg->hwnd );
      if( pWnd )
      {
            if( pMsg->message == WM_MOUSEWHEEL )
            {
                    CRuntimeClass* pRuntimeClass = pWnd->GetRuntimeClass();
                    bool bIsCombo = pRuntimeClass->IsDerivedFrom( RUNTIME_CLASS(CComboBox) ) || pWnd->IsKindOf( RUNTIME_CLASS(CComboBox) );

                    if( bIsCombo && !reinterpret_cast<CComboBox*>(pWnd)->GetDroppedState() )
                         return TRUE;
            }
       }

       return CFrameWndEx::PreTranslateMessage( pMsg );

}
```

However, this doesn't work because the runtime class always seems to be `CWnd`, so I'm curious to know if there's a way to get this to work? Using a `dynamic_cast` from `CWnd*` to `CComboBox*` also didn't appear to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`GetClassName`, which is what Captain Obvlious shows above is workable solution and will do what you want.

Of course, the *sane* solution (which I show in the question you link to) is to simply create a class derived from `CComboBox` and handle the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` there in whichever way you feel is appropriate for your application. Then you can use the derived class instead of `CComboBox` simply by changing `CComboBox` to `CNoScrollComboBox` or whatever you name your class.

It's really quite simple and saves you a **whole lot of trouble**.

Answer (score 1):

If the parent window does not subclass the combo box with `CComboBox` (or other suitable CWnd derived class) MFC will return a pointer to a temporary CWnd object. You have two options here. Subclass the combobox window when the parent is created  (in `OnCreate` on `OnInitDialog`) -OR- call `GetClassName()` and check the type of the target window when you handle the mouse wheel message.